# Keep WebSocket and some event handlers alive while app is active

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

I use Caliburn.Micro to build a Windows 8.1 Universal app. The app connects to a web service using a WebSocket. I would like this connection, once established, to be kept alive as long as the app is active, no matter what page the user is on.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
container = new WinRTContainer();
container.Singleton<IConnectionService, ConnectionService>();
```

and it seems to work as I want to. I can inject it in my viewmodels and the connection is still open and it does receive messages even when a view model that does not inject the service is active. I am however a bit curious if this is the correct way (and if it's actually doing what I'm expecting)?

Secondly, I'm using the connection manager to parse the JSON returned from the WebSocket connection and creating corresponding classes like `RandomThingHappened` and broadcasting these using the event aggregator service from Caliburn.Micro. View interested in these can subscribe and do what they want. However, there are some messages that I would like handled regardless of which view the user is on. Is this possible? I've thought about creating singletons for this as well, and just make sure to instantiate these somewhere. That does however seem a bit... risky.

Suggestions?

Comment: No experience with Caliburn so take this with a grain of salt, but perhaps you can create an additional layer in your view inheritance to define a baseview that implements those events?

Comment: That sure is a nice idea @JeroenVannevel, I will give that a try!

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure about websocket but

I am using the following ways for My WCF service ( the dumb terminal must be always connected cause the WCF service will push message to connected terminal using callback

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void KeepConnection();
```

and in your client use a timer to keep calling the service

```
   var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 50) };
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (this.client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                    {
                        this.RegisterTerminal();
                    }

                    this.client.KeepConnection();
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to establish connection with server");
                }
            };
```

As for the broadcasting you can use EventAggregator to publish your event to all the listening class.

you can read it more here [Event Aggregator](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator)